# Complex grouping or case statement giving me headache

Tags: sql-server-2012, grouping

I'm working in SQL Server 2012 and what I am trying to achieve is the following three forms of criteria, here goes I hope this makes sense

With data similar to that below, if I have two contracts with a Total Value > 0 for each user code on each row then the result I would need to be 'Multiple Contracts' e.g. Sites 52, 70, 309 below, if I have two contracts where there is a Total Value > 0 on only 1 of the rows then the result would then be the contract name of the user where the Total Value is > 0 e.g. Site 520, finally if I have a contract where there is only one then this simply just results in that given contract name e.g. Site 600.

```
Site  UserCode   User Name             Contract Name         Total Val
----------------------------------------------------------------------
52    10000123   Miss Brenda Smith     Perm Contract         425.00
52    10000123   Miss Brenda Smith     Temp Contract         772.00
70    10000300   Mr Paul Jones         Perm Contract         877.00
70    10000300   Mr Paul Jones         Another Contract       29.00
309   10000297   Mrs Annette Curtain   Yet Another Contract  255.00
309   10000297   Mrs Annette Curtain   Perm Contract          61.00
520   10000140   Miss Alison Smith     Perm Contract         425.00
520   10000140   Miss Alison Smith     Temp Contract           0.00
600   10000200   Mr Steve Myself       Perm Contract         100.00
```

This has been a serious headache for me and I have hit a wall and cannot do it, it's driving me crazy and would love it if someone could help me. I've tried with various case statements etc. but had a brain meltdown. It's probably simple but having stared at it for so long I've gone blind.

Comment: Your text is missing details.  What exactly is your question - it looks like you want code that captures your logic, but you don't say so clearly?  What language are you working in, or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Hi sorry the description was a little confusing, I've added to this and hopefully it makes a little more sense. I am in SQL 2012 and need help with the code to work out from the example data given.

Comment: Well, for starters here's a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e64a7/1/0) but maybe you want to show us what you've tried and how it's not what you're after?

Comment: The statements have been messed around with that much they don't work now at all, its the whole thing that I'm having real trouble getting to grips with.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into logical segments.  I can't think of one query that'll handle your conditions, so I wrote 3 and I `union` them together.

It's not perfect, but it works.

```
declare @contracts table
(
  Site         INT,
  UserCode     INT,
  UserName     VARCHAR(100),
  ContractName VARCHAR(100),
  TotalVal     MONEY
);


INSERT INTO @contracts (Site,UserCode,UserName,ContractName,TotalVal) VALUES
(52, 10000123, 'Miss Brenda Smith',   'Perm Contract',        425.00),
(52, 10000123, 'Miss Brenda Smith',   'Temp Contract',        772.00),
(70, 10000300, 'Mr Paul Jones',       'Perm Contract',        877.00),
(70, 10000300, 'Mr Paul Jones',       'Another Contract',     29.00),
(309,10000297, 'Mrs Annette Curtain', 'Yet Another Contract', 255.00),
(309,10000297, 'Mrs Annette Curtain', 'Perm Contract',        61.00),
(520,10000140, 'Miss Alison Smith',   'Perm Contract',        425.00),
(520,10000140, 'Miss Alison Smith',   'Temp Contract',        0.00),
(600,10000200, 'Mr Steve Myself',     'Perm Contract',        100.00);

select t1.Site, UserCode, UserName, 'multiple contracts', SUM(TotalVal) as totalvalue
from @contracts t1
join (select site from @contracts where TotalVal>0 group by Site having COUNT(*)>1) as morethan1greater0
   on t1.Site=morethan1greater0.Site
group by t1.Site, UserCode, UserName
union all
select t1.Site, UserCode, UserName, ContractName, SUM(t1.TotalVal) as totalvalue
from @contracts t1
join (select site, sum(TotalVal) TotalVal from @contracts group by Site having COUNT(*)>1) as morethan1only1greater0
   on t1.Site=morethan1only1greater0.Site
   and t1.TotalVal=morethan1only1greater0.TotalVal
group by t1.Site, UserCode, UserName, ContractName
union all
select t1.Site, UserCode, UserName, ContractName, SUM(TotalVal) as totalvalue
from @contracts t1
join (select site from @contracts group by Site having COUNT(*)=1) as only1
   on t1.Site=only1.Site
group by t1.Site, UserCode, UserName, ContractName
```